# Number Value Input Exception

Tags: c#

I trying to solve this code so it repeats exception until input is a number. right now it stop right first attempt and I do know how to place while loop.

```
int nomer2;
            WriteLine("Write Number");


            try
            {
                nomer2 = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                WriteLine("here is my Number {0}", nomer2);

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                WriteLine("Error: Enter Number");
            }
```

Comment: you cannot learn a language one keyword at a time by asking questions on stackoverflow.  I would suggest attending a programming course, or opening up a book, or searching for "C# sample" + keyword of interest.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
while(!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out nomer2))
{
   WriteLine("Write Number");
}

   WriteLine("here is my Number {0}", nomer2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its recommended not to use exceptions unless it is really unexpected what the result would be. You can use the TryParse function which tries to convert the string that is passed to it to an integer. If the conversion was successful, the integer is returned by reference in the second param and the function returns true, otherwise, it returns false.

```
int nomer2;
string input = string.Empty;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write Number");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!int.TryParse(input, out nomer2)) ;

Console.WriteLine("here is my Number {0}", nomer2);
```

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Comment: That's a lot better, thanks.